# Get a hint when a hidden view is visible

Tags: android, listview

I don't seem to have a proper title for the question but I will try to describe it as good as I can. Here is the scenario.
I have a listview with each listview row having a hidden view associated with it. When user taps on row hidden view becomes visible.
Suppose listview has 3 items, and when user taps on first row, it expands and remaining two views are shifted down giving user a hint that the view has expanded. But with the last row when user taps on that row, view does become visible but as that view is completely at bottom of the screen, it expands below it and it is completely unclear whether it expands or not.
So what I want to know whether it is possible that we can scroll that view up a bit so that user will get to know that view has expanded or any other way to do it.
Any ideas will be really appreciated and I hope I have described it well enough

Here is the xml of row layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/frame">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/iv_routes"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="@string/routes_name"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_routes"/>
    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/route_hidden">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas interdum placerat sodales. Etiam fringilla nibh eget dictum iaculis."
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_long_description_routes"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/right"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/nextScreen"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="#D6D6D6"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/up"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/routes_up"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why dont you use expandable listview??

Comment: I tried using it but I found that it is different from my scenario

Comment: post you code. otherwise its not possible to understand your situation to the point

Comment: I will post it . In my case I am also having buttons and text in hidden view therefore I didn't get how to use it with expandable listview